# How do i use Switch for inline keyboard and replykeyboard at the same time #PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

here is a php telegram webhook script:

```
//calling telegram api after setting $access_token with the bot api
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

                //setting variables from telegram api
                $chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
                $first_name = $output['message']['chat']['first_name'];
                $last_name  = $output["message"]["chat"]["last_name"];
                $message = $output['message']['text'];
                $callback_query = $output['callback_query'];
                $data = $callback_query['data'];
                $message_id = ['callback_query']['message']['message_id'];
                $chat_id_in = $callback_query['message']['chat']['id'];  
                 switch($message) {
                     case '/start':
                     $inline_button1 = array("text"=>"Website","url"=>"http://google.com");
                     $inline_button2 = array("text"=>"test","callback_data"=>'/test');
                     $inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1,$inline_button2]];
                     $keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
                     $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);
                      sendMessage($chat_id, "hello", $replyMarkup);
                     break;
                     case '/help':
                     sendMessage($chat_id,"you need help?",$replyMarkup);
                     break;
                     default:
                     sendMessage($chat_id,"thank you",$replyMarkup);
                 }
                switch($data){
                    case '/test':
                    sendMessage($chat_id_in, "Coming Soon .....");
                    break;
                }
    //the sendMessage function
                function sendMessage($chat_id, $message, $replyMarkup) {
                  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message) . '&reply_markup=' . $replyMarkup);
                }
```

The Code above works fine for me with inline keyboard on telegram, but i like to add `replykeyboard` along with some command but am having issue with it see below . I think its the curl function i need to get right, what is your thought guys .

How can you help me?

```
        $api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
        $output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
        $chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
        $first_name = $output['message']['chat']['first_name'];
        $last_name  = $output["message"]["chat"]["last_name"];
        $message = $output['message']['text'];
        $callback_query = $output['callback_query'];
        $data = $callback_query['data'];
        $message_id = ['callback_query']['message']['message_id'];
        $chat_id_in = $callback_query['message']['chat']['id'];  
         switch($message) {
             case '/start':
             $inline_button1 = array("text"=>"Website","url"=>"http://google.com");
             $inline_button2 = array("text"=>"test","callback_data"=>'/test');
             $inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1,$inline_button2]];
             $keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
             $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);
              sendMessage($chat_id, "Hello", $replyMarkup);
             break;
             case '/help':
             $keyboard1 = array("text"=>"Button 1","text"=>"Button 1","resize_keyboard"=>'true',"one_time_keyboard"=>'true');
             $keyboard2 = array("text"=>"Button 2","text"=>"Button 2","resize_keyboard"=>'true',"one_time_keyboard"=>'true');
             $keyboardset = [[$keyboard1,$keyboard2]];
             $keyboard=array("KeyboardButton"=>$keyboardset)
             $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);
             sendMessage($chat_id,"$you need help",$replyMarkup);
             break;
             default:
             sendMessage($chat_id,"$Thanks",$replyMarkup);
         }
        switch($data){
            case '/test':
            sendMessage($chat_id_in, "Coming Soon .....");
            break;
        }



//call the curl $ch = curl_init($api . 'sendMessage');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($data)); curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

            function sendMessage($chat_id, $message, $replyMarkup) {
              file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message) . '&reply_markup=' .
        $replyMarkup);
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code

```
 $api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
        $output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
        $chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
        $first_name = $output['message']['chat']['first_name'];
        $last_name  = $output["message"]["chat"]["last_name"];
        $message = $output['message']['text'];
        $callback_query = $output['callback_query'];
        $data = $callback_query['data'];
        $message_id = ['callback_query']['message']['message_id'];
        $chat_id_in = $callback_query['message']['chat']['id'];  
         switch($message) {
             case '/start':
             $inline_button1 = array("text"=>"Website","url"=>"http://google.com");
             $inline_button2 = array("text"=>"test","callback_data"=>'/test');
             $inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1,$inline_button2]];
             $keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
             $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);
              sendMessage($chat_id, "Hello", $replyMarkup);
             break;
             case '/help':
             $keyboard = array(array("Cancel","Go Ahead","test"));
   $resp = array("keyboard" => $keyboard,"resize_keyboard" => true,"one_time_keyboard" => true);
   $reply_ = json_encode($resp);
             break;
             default:
             sendMessage($chat_id,"$Thanks",$replyMarkup);
         }
        switch($data){
            case '/test':
            sendMessage($chat_id_in, "Coming Soon .....");
            break;
        }
```

Thanks